# Why are my depth values in this freaky range?

Tags: opengl, range, glsl, depth-buffer, deferred-rendering

In my deferred renderer, the depth buffer holds values in the range from about `0.9700` to `1.0000`. I found this out by drawing pixels in a given depth range black. This is the shader code I used.

```
bool inrange(in float position)
{
    float z = texture2D(depth, coord).r;
    return abs(position - z) < 0.0001;
}

void main()
{
    if(inrange(0.970)) image = vec3(0);
    else result = texture2D(image, coord);
}
```

And this is how it looks like. I tried several depth values. This image is for the depth value `0.998`.

[image: screenshot]

I use a as texture of the type `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` and format `GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV` as depth and stencil attachment.

Is there an explanation for my depth values to be in this range? Is it default behavior? I would like them to be in the range of `0.0000` and `1.0000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a perspective near clipping plane very close to the origin. When building the perspective matrix try to set the near clipping as far as possible from the origin.

Comment: My clipping planes are at `0.1f` and `1000.0f`. But I need the near plane to be that near, so that object near the player aren't cut. But can I correct the depth range then? I haven't understand the mathematics behind that completely.

Comment: @danijar: The near plane so close is what causes your problem. In a perspective projection the Z value maps nonlinearily to depth values, specifically it's d(z) ∝ 1/z, which means that for a very close near plane you're compressing all the depth precision into a very small distance from the origin.

Comment: If objects really get that close the viewer there are several strategies. First strategy *multipass rendering*: 1st render the world and far objects using the usual projection. That for all objects closer than a certain threshold perform a 2nd pass, by clearing only the depth buffer. Then with a projection with different depth range render the closer objects.

Comment: @danijar: Another approach would be to linearize or adjust the depth values in the fragment shader. However be advised that modifying the depth value in the fragment shader comes with a certain performance penality.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I modify the depth value in the fragment shader to become linear and normalized? Why can't I do so in the vertex shader with `gl_Position.z = ...`?

Comment: @danijar: The nonlinearity of the depth value stems from the homogenous divide that's applied to the gl_Position value emitted by the vertex shader. It is this homogenous divide that creates a perspective effect so if you want a perspective effect you must not counter that linearity. Depth testing is a framebuffer operations, so you want to fix the framebuffer depth values, not the clip space vertex position. In the fragment shader there's a special builtin variable `gl_FragDepth`. You can overwrite that using a value determined from linear, view space vertex Z coordinates.

Comment: However, overriding `gl_FragDepth` might come with a price tag, because [early depth testing](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test) won't work anymore. You could test how much it costs you by adding `gl_FragDepth = gl_FragCoord.z;` in your fragment shader. If overdraw is an issue for you, you could try adding an initial depth pass to your pipeline.

Comment: @danijar Forgot the notification for my previous comment.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg: What you wrote about is that "performance penality" I wrote about in my 3rd comment.